# React TypeScript How to attach an event listener to window.matchMedia

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

When the react page loads it detects if the user has set dark mode in their operating system

```
const darkMode = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches;
```

and then renders one of two images depending on the result

```
import logoDark from '../images/logoDark.svg';
import logoLight from '../images/logoLight.svg';

<img src={darkMode ? logoDark : logoLight} />
```

But if the user changes mode after the page has loaded the image isn't updated, how do I add an event listener to window.matchMedia ?

I have tried with..

```
  darkMode.addEventListener( "change", (e) => {
    darkMode = e.matches;
    console.log(e.matches) // true / false
  });
```

but I get the error `Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'MediaQueryList'.ts(2322)`

**UDATE**: Working Code

```
import React, {useContext} from "react";
import Context from '../components/context';
import logoDark from '../images/logoDark.svg';
import logoLight from '../images/logoLight.svg';

const Home: React.FC = () => {
  const darkMode = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)');   
  darkMode.addEventListener( "change", (e) => {
    if (e.matches) {
      setGlobal({...global, mode: true})
    } else {
      setGlobal({...global, mode: false})
    }
  });
  return (
  <img src={global.mode ? logoDark : logoLight} />
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: I don't think it emits an event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding eventListener on matches, which is boolean. You have to do it like below code:

```js
var darkMode = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)');

darkMode.addEventListener( "change", (e) => {
    if (e.matches) {
    //Perform your action for dark
  } else {
    //Perform other action
  }
})
```

Comment: I still get the same error `Type 'true' is not assignable to type 'MediaQueryList'.` the error comes on darkMode in `    if (e.matches) {
      darkMode = true;
    } else {
      darkMode = false;
    }`

Comment: DarkMode points to window.watchMedia. You can not assign true false to it. Check for your key

Comment: you have to make showHide as part of the component state. something like const [showHide] = React.useState(0); then use it

Answer (score 0):

`darkMode` is a state that has `type` value if I understand correctly. And if it is not it should be in state in order to manipulate it. The type e.matches returns is a Boolean as you see. So, you need to change the `darkMode` type to Boolean..

And setState, base on the condition. I do not have the complete code so, I will not make guesses. If you paste more code samples I can help more..

Answer (score 0):

For a functional component you are probably looking for something like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const throttleUpdate = throttle((ev: MediaQueryListEvent) => setIsSmallScreen(ev.matches), 150);
    // 768 = md, https://ant.design/components/layout#breakpoint-width
    const matchMedia = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 768px)');
    matchMedia.addEventListener('change', throttleUpdate);
    return () => matchMedia.removeEventListener('change', throttleUpdate);
  }, []);
```